# Set Typeface for View Holder TextView using Dagger2 DI

Tags: android, dagger, typeface

I want to set a custom typeface for a Textview in ListView Adapter ViewHolder.
My typeface font file is in assets folder, so I will need a context reference in my adapter class to access the assets path and also I don't want to pass a context reference to my adapter class constructor.
Should I use context reference through Dagger2 DI or should I make a separate DI Component to get reference of my font Typeface class.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: show some relevant code of your adpater and view holder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `ViewHolder` you have access to `View` and all `View`s have access to context by `getContext` method.

Comment: thanx. its working.Also should I make a separate DI component to get access to my Typeface file reference? or continue to access it via getContext??

Comment: I prefer to have a singleton manager to hold and change Typefaces. Then I inject this manager by my app component(my main component) instead of all the time reading needed Typefaces from resources.